# Is an English translation of Leibnitz's paper on calculus available?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

So, I was trying to go through "[Nova methodus pro maximis et minimis, itemque tangentibus,…, & singulare pro illis calculi genus](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasure-leibnizs-papers-on-calculus-differential-calculus)". However the paper is in a language I don't know (Latin maybe). This is one of the earliest published works on the modern calculus.

Is there an English translation of this great work available?

Comment: Yes, that's in Latin. You probably don't want to study Latin just for that paper, but if there are any questions, there's a [Latin Language Stack Exchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Impossible... If those guys are ready to translate the whole paper into english then it would be helpful... that's probably not possible.;-)

Comment: That'd be a more than mild case of "too broad". :) What I meant is that if some turn of phrase sounds weird in a translation and you want to compare against the original (or some such thing for a smaller passage), then a question would be welcome.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Sure but at this point I just can't make any sense out of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good source for this sort of stuff is David Eugene Smith's book [A source book in mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486646904). It has collected a bunch of important mathematical papers through history. In particular, there is a partial translation of that Leibniz's paper by 
Evelyn Walker (under the title "Leibniz on the Calculus", at page 619 in the copy I have (a Dover edition)).

An online copy of the book (1929 edition) is available [here](https://archive.org/stream/sourcebookinmath00smit#page/620/mode/2up).

Comment: The book is not available in my country via the online sellers.;-(

Comment: Can you upload a page or two maybe in your answer?

Comment: @talan archive.org seems to have a [copy](https://archive.org/details/sourcebookinmath00smit) of the whole  book (1929 edition), it is on page 619 there.

Comment: Thanks! It helped...

Answer (score 2):

The wikipedia article on the paper,
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_Methodus_pro_Maximis_et_Minimis,
contains a link to this PDF file which seems to be exactly what you want:
http://17centurymaths.com/contents/Leibniz/nova1.pdf